# How to use CuraEngine From command Line in ubuntu?

Tags: command-line

The CuraEngine allows to convert the .stl files to .gcode

I am new to 3d printing, is any one familiar with curaEngine.

Can I have a example of commandLine Creation of gcode.
Or can anyone suggest me a tool for converting stl files to gcode via command line in ubuntu

Comment: https://github.com/KrisRoofe/curaengine-dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

supporse you are running the curaengine on ubuntu14.04LTS.
according to the [curaengine manual](https://github.com/Ultimaker/CuraEngine)

```
git clone
    https://github.com/Ultimaker/CuraEngine.git
    https://github.com/google/protobuf.git
    https://github.com/Ultimaker/libArcus.git
```

compile the protobuf

arrording to https://github.com/Ultimaker/CuraEngine#installing-protobuf, you can success this step.

compile the libArcus
according to https://github.com/Ultimaker/libArcus#installing-protobuf

but when you run the `make ..`, you will come to an error.
~/libArcus/build$ cmake ..

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES) (Required is at least
  version "3.4")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPythonLibs.cmake:208 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/lufei/libArcus/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

then `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`

the key step is install the pip

```
wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/sip/sip-4.18.1/sip-4.18.1.tar.gz
tar xzvf sip-4.18.1.tar.gz
cd sip-4.18.1
python3 ./configure.py
make
sudo make install
```

comment the 28th line ../cmake/FindSIP.cmake to ignore the pythonn-dev check, as you have install the python3-dev. then you can sussecc compile the libarcus.

compile the curaengine
to compile curaengine you need g++ 4.8, while g++4.8 install in ubuntu14.04lts.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9
sudo apt-get install g++-4.9
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-4.9 /usr/bin/g++ -f
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 /usr/bin/gcc -f
```

when you compile the curaengine it will output ERROR ...., just ignore it.
then everything done.

just run `./CuraEngine slice -j ~/prusa_i3.def.json -o output.gcode -l ~/source.stl`
the prusa_i3.def.json and the fdmprinter.def.json you need download from the cura repo.

Answer (score 1):

just run `CuraEngine help` It should be up to date...

Don't forget to take a look at [fdmprinter.def.json](https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/blob/master/resources/definitions/fdmprinter.def.json) to see all (300+) settings.